# Undefined method `i18n_scope' for RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rspec-rails, rspec2, rspec-mocks

I recently upgraded to Rails 4. When I ran my RSpec tests I got an error.

Here is my spec:

```
1   model = double(:model, errors: double(:errors, full_messages: []))
2   transaction = double(:transaction)
3   transaction.stub(:update_attributes!) { raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(model) }
```

I got the error `<NoMethodError: undefined method 'i18n_scope' for RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class>` in line 3.

[Per the API documentation 'i18n_scope' has been removed from Rails 4.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/i18n_scope/class)

Comment: I answered your question + offered a "cleaner" alternative here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037136/stub-i18n-scope-for-mocking-activerecordrecordinvalid-on-rails-4-rspec-3-3-0/34361086#34361086

Answer (score -1):

```
RSpec::Mocks::Mock.stub(:i18n_scope).and_return(:activerecord)
model = double(:model, errors: double(:errors, full_messages: []))
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(model)
```

Not sure why RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class was looking for 'i18n_scope' method. But to fix it, I stubbed 'i18n_scope'. Then it works.

Comment: This isn't correct. The double class is `RSpec::Mocks::Double`. This class also doesn't implement `i18n_scope`. You can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037136/stub-i18n-scope-for-mocking-activerecordrecordinvalid-on-rails-4-rspec-3-3-0/34361086#34361086. At least for RSpec 3.3+